# Not JSON serializable - Python + Flask + Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am writing small query to fetch the data from `mysql` database, 
I have a report table, inside that I have `report_id`, I need to query the data which matched `report_id` coming from `api` params.

My function:

```
def view_single_thumbnail(idx): // idx coming from params 
    session = Session()

    result = session.query(
        Report
    ).filter(
        Report.report_id == idx
    ).all()

    return jsonify({
        'data': result
    })
```

Throwing error: `'components.db.core.table_declaration.Report object at 0x000001C1Fsdfsdf51E6A90' is not JSON serializable`.

Answer (score 8):

SQLAlchemy objects cannot be serialized automatically by `jsonify`. You can add a property to your SQLAlchemy model `class`

```
class Report(db.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    @property
    def serialized(self):
        """Return object data in serializeable format"""
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'report_text': "Some text",
            ...
        }
```

And you view will update to this:

```
def view_single_thumbnail(idx): // idx coming from params 
    session = Session()

    result = session.query(
        Report
    ).filter(
        Report.report_id == idx
    ).all()

    return jsonify({
        'data': [result.serialized for result in results]
    })
```

Comment: i cant understand this, i am beginner for python/flask. where i need to put this?

Comment: You have to add the property to the `Report` class. When you add the property `serialize` jsonify will call it to get a serializable dictionary.

Comment: it should be `result.serialize` (without brackets) instead of `result.serialize()`

Comment: Ah, I'll fix that. Thanks, you are awesome! (pun intended)

Answer (score 2):

The result from a query is an Object if I remember correctly, you should convert it into a `dict` first before trying to convert it into a json. I've used a simple `lambda` function to do mine in a older project

```
# Lambda vesion
# row2dict = lambda r: {c.name: str(getattr(r, c.name)) for c in r.__table__.columns}

# Function version
def row2dict(row):
    return {
        c.name: str(getattr(row, c.name))
        for c in row.__table__.columns
    }

def view_single_thumbnail(idx): // idx coming from params 
    session = Session()

    result = [
           row2dict(report)
           for report in session.query(Report)
                  .filter(Report.report_id == idx)
                  .all()
    ]

    return jsonify({
        'data': result
    })
```

Comment: is there any method without using third party libraries like lambda?

Comment: `lamba` is a built in keyword in python. It's just a simplified way of declaring a function.

Comment: whats the row2dict actually do?

Comment: By default the `query` returns an object instead of an serializeable object. What `row2dict` does is it runs through all the attributes of your object, `Report` object for this case, and then converts that into a `dict`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Report' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: What does your `Report` class look like?